# AvalonDock: Change background of title when focused

Tags: wpf, avalondock

I want to change the background of the pane title, if the pane is focused.

So tried this:

```
    <Style TargetType="xcad:AnchorablePaneTitle">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Green background is applied, but if i select a control in the pane, no red is shown.
Special side effect: if i unpin the pane, the background of the title is set to default. If i pin it, it set to green.

How its possible to change it on focus?

Comment: According to your XAML markup, this can only work if you focus the pane **header**. What you're probably trying to achieve, is to make the header red when a pane is active (that means, its content has focus). Right?

Comment: Yes, thats right. If the content is selected/focused, it should be red

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues with you current solution.

Styling the `AnchorablePaneTitle` does only work when the pane is docked into the `DockingManager`. As soon as you undock the pane, there is no `AnchorablePaneTitle` anymore, because AvalonDock changes the root element to a `LayoutFloatingWindowControl`, which has a different structure.

The second issue is that you're using the `IsFocused` property. This won't work, because the `AnchorablePaneTitle` cannot be focused at all (its's just a `TextBlock` by default).

To make this work, you have to create a `DataTemplate` for the title using the `AnchorableTitleTemplate` property of the `DockingManager`.

Here is an example:

```
<xcad:DockingManager.AnchorableTitleTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Grid">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Model.IsActive, Mode=OneWay, 
                             RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type xcad:LayoutAnchorableControl}},
                             FallbackValue=False}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsKeyboardFocusWithin, Mode=OneWay,
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type xcad:LayoutFloatingWindowControl}},
                            FallbackValue=False}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                </Style>
            </Grid.Style>
            <TextBlock Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Title}" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</xcad:DockingManager.AnchorableTitleTemplate>
```

Here I create two data triggers that react on different properties depending on which mode the anchorable is currently in: docked or undocked.

For the docked state, I use the `Model.IsActive` property, which works well.
For the undocked (floating) state I first tried the `IsActive` property of the `xcad:LayoutFloatingWindowControl` (which derives from a `Window`), but it was always `true` for all floating windows. Maybe this is because all of them have an `Owner` (the main window). So I just decided to use the `IsKeyboardFocusWithin`, which works very well for the floating windows.